# Getting IE text-shadow polyfill to work with Modernizr

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, modernizr, css

I am trying to get a small polyfill (https://github.com/heygrady/textshadow) to add text-shadow effect on Internet Explorer to work, but can't seem to figure out how to make it work. This is the code I'm using:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/modernizr.custom.61772.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    Modernizr.load({
        test: Modernizr.textshadow,
        nope: ['/Content/jquery.textshadow.css', '/Scripts/jquery.textshadow.js'],
        complete: function () {
            $('h1').textshadow('1px 1px 2px #111')
        }
    });
</script>
```

I do get an effect but it looks all wrong. I just end up with the original heading text all over again, with the exact same formatting as the original text, but offset towards the bottom by half a line height.

EDIT: So after some experimenting I found out that I can at least get the shadow effect by manually creating the CSS rules for the class, rather than relying on javascript to do so, like so:

```
h1 .ui-text-shadow-copy 
{
    color: #111; /* color */
    filter:
        progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Blur(makeShadow=false,pixelRadius=2); /* blue */
    left: 0px; /* left - blur */
    top: 0px; /* top - blur */
}
```

But the positioning is still screwed up. With left 0px and top 0px the shadow is placed half a line below the text. With anything else pieces of the shadow is spread out around the page.

Answer (score 2):

I got it to work but I had to override the css styling inside the .textshadow method to get it to look right.  Here's what worked for me:

CSS for browsers that support  text-shadow:

```
.ts {
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #111111;
  -moz-text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #111111;
  -webkit-text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #111111;
}
```

Modernizr.load:

```
Modernizr.load([
    {// load jquery
       load: '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.js',
       complete: function () {
            if (!window.jQuery) {
                Modernizr.load('/TimeTracker/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js');
            }
    }
    },
    {//other scripts that depend on jquery, including jquery ui
        load: ['some.js','some.other.js']
    },
    {
       test: Modernizr.textshadow,
       nope: ['/url/to/jquery.textshadow.css','/url/to/jquery.textshadow.js']
    },
    '/url/to/file/that/contains/document.ready.js'
]);
```

document.ready.js:

```
var m = window.Modernizr;

function loadJqueryTextshadow() {
    $('.ts').textshadow('2px -12px 2px #111111');
}

$(function(){
    if (!m.textshadow) {
        loadJqueryTextshadow();
    }
}
```

The end result is close enough that the majority of users would never know the difference between IE, Chrome, and Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Microsoft `DropShadow` css filter for that:

```
h1 .ui-text-shadow-copy {
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.DropShadow(Color=#111111, OffX=1, OffY=1);
}
```

---

Where:

- *Color* is RGB value for shadow
- *Offx* - pixels for shadow offset by x
- *Offy* - pixels for shadow offset by y

Comment: The problem is that the Microsoft DropShadow filter is incredibly ugly compared to the blur filter. That is the reason I'm using this polyfill instead of the DropShadow filter to begin with.

Comment: Do you have some example? At jsFiddle for example.

Comment: There are a bunch of comparisons by the author who made the polyfill here: http://heygrady.com/blog/2011/03/10/css-text-shadows-in-internet-explorer/

Comment: This is a ressource: How to do dropshadow filter right http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2011/04/14/css3-text-shadow-can-it-be-done-in-ie-without-javascript/

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer: forget about text-shadow in IE. There is nothing available that can render close enough to other browsers.

Answer (score -1):

you can use Css3Pie to text-shadow and border-radius:

http://css3pie.com/

```
Modernizr.load([
{
test: Modernizr.borderradius && Modernizr.boxshadow,
nope: 'PIE.htc' }
]); /*fine load modernizr*/
```

Comment: It does not look like CSS3Pie support text-shadow, only box-shadow.